# REST API integration problem

Tags: integration

We are trying to use the REST API in salesforce. As of now we are using connected app OAuth authentication.Everything is good when we tested in Postman but when we are trying to connect salesforce with local host CORS issue is raised even when we have whitelisted in salesforce.Is there some way to resolve the issue.
 And I had a question which is the best way to implement Authentication process?
[image]

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of your connected app configuration?

Comment: What grant type are you using?

Comment: I am using password for  grant type